# python pandas: computing argmax of column in matrix subset

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, argmax

Consider toy dataframes df1 and df2, where df2 is a subset of df1 (excludes the first row).

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[3.0,9,45,7],'colB':['A','B','C','D']})
df2 = df1[1:]
```

Now lets find argmax of colA for each frame

```
np.argmax(df1.colA) ## result is "2", which is what I expected
np.argmax(df2.colA) ## result is still "2", which is not what I expected.  I expected "1"
```

If my matrix of insterest is df2, how do I get around this indexing issue?  Is this quirk related to pandas, numpy, or just python memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's due to index. You could use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) when you assign `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[3.0,9,45,7],'colB':['A','B','C','D']})
df2 = df1[1:].reset_index(drop=True)

In [464]: np.argmax(df1.colA)
Out[464]: 2

In [465]: np.argmax(df2.colA)
Out[465]: 1
```

I think it's better to use method [`argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) instead of `np.argmax`:

```
In [467]: df2.colA.argmax()
Out[467]: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the index of `df2`:

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
np.argmax(df2.colA)
>> 1
```